# error in react Native while show featch json data in render()

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

I'm new to  React - native development. I  have  this  json  data  need to  show  in  render() using **{this.state.data.min.en}**

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "good",
  "data": {
    "min": {
      "sin": "text",
      "en": " text",
      "ta": "text",
      "ownere": "  text"
    }
  }
}
```

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  AppRegistry,
  Alert
} from "react-native";
import { Card } from "react-native-elements";

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  handlePress = async () => {
    fetch("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/index.php/testCV/home", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({ data: responseJson.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handlePress();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Card>{this.state.data.min.en}</Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Home", () => Home);
```

I  try  it  using  above code  but when i run it i get  this  error. I try to find   way to  fix it but  no luck.

[image]

It's very grateful someone can help me out with this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defaulting your data to an empty array, so when you write `this.state.data.min` you will get `undefined`, and then trying to access `en` on that will give rise to your error.

You could e.g. default the `data` to `null`, and wait until your data has been loaded before rendering it.

**Example**

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    if (data === null) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Card>{data.min.en}</Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```